# How to use Schur's decomposition on more than two commuting matrices?

Tags: matrices

If we have more than two square matrices $A$, $B$, $C$,... commute, how can we prove that there exits a unitary matrix $U$ such that  $U$ * $A$ $U$,  $U$ * $B$ $U$, $U$ * $C$ $U$,.... are upper triangular matrices?
Following from Schur's decomposition for two commuting matrices, it works.But for more than two,I tried to prove it by induction but could'nt reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point lies in the proof of Schur decomposition. Let $A^{(1)}, A^{(2)}, \cdots, A^{(k)}$ be $k$ square matrices which mutually commute with one another. Let the set of eigenvalues of $A^{(j)}$ be $\{\lambda^{(j)}_1, \cdots, \lambda^{(j)}_{n_j}\}$. Also let the eigenspace of $A^{(j)}$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda^{(j)}_{s}$ be denote by $V^{(j)}_s$.

Now if $v\in V^{(1)}_j$ for some $j\leq n_1$, then since $A^{(1)}, A^{(2)}$ commute, we have $A^{(1)}A^{(2)}v=A^{(2)}A^{(1)}v=\lambda^{(1)}_jA^{(2)}v$. So $A^{(2)}v\in V^{(1)}_j$ too, meaning $A^{(2)}$ leaves $V_j^{(1)}$ invariant. As a result $V_{m_1}^{(1)}\cap V_{m_2}^{(2)}$ is not only invariant under both $A^{(1)}, A^{(2)}$, but both matrices act on $V_{m_1}^{(1)}\cap V_{m_2}^{(2)}$ diagonally. Similarly one can decompose $V$ into:

$$
V=\bigoplus_{m_1, \cdots, m_k} \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k V^{(i)}_{m_i}\right)
$$
where $m_j\leq n_j$ in the above sum. You can see that all $A^{(i)}$ leave $U_{m_1, \cdots, m_k}:=\bigcap_{i=1}^k V^{(i)}_{m_i}$ invariant and act on it diagonally. Now choose an orthonormal basis $Z_{m_1, \cdots, m_k}$ for $U_{m_1, \cdots, m_k}$. This gives you a unitary matrix $T$ such that $A^{(i)}=T^*F^{(i)}T$ with $F^{(i)}$ upper-triangular.